# Bitwise shift in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

There is a port number stored in two bytes, and I want to return it back as integer. Here the code:

```
Dim PORT As Integer
PORT = (req.Skip(req.Skip(4).Take(1).ToArray()(0) + 5).Take(1).ToArray()(0) << 8) + req.Skip(req.Skip(4).Take(1).ToArray()(0) + 6).Take(1).ToArray()(0)
```

But this doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Results should be like this: 25 << 8 => 6400 + 145 => 6545

But this is what I got: 25 + 145 => 145

Comment: Doesn't work: Returns wrong result? Throws an exception? Causes the universe to cease to exist?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever wrong result.

Comment: What is the result you get & what is the result you want?

Comment: In addition to what Phil's asked, we could do with an example of the array (or whatever `req` is) itself.

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: The first question would be: where the hell did you get that formula from and what is it supposed to do? This doesn’t look at all like what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert (at least one of) your operands to the shift operation to a larger data type.

From [`<<`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7haw1dex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Arithmetic shifts are not circular, which means the bits shifted off one end of the result are not reintroduced at the other end. In an arithmetic left shift, the bits shifted beyond the range of the result data type are discarded, and the bit positions vacated on the right are set to zero.

So it needs to be something like:

```
CInt(25) << 8 + 145
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what your code does, not what it’s supposed to do but based on your example:

```
Dim result = CInt(req(0)) << 8 Or req(1)
```

(You can also use `+` instead of `Or`, it won’t change a thing but using a bitwise or here feels vaguely more correct.)

Even simpler, using [the framework’s builtin methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint16.aspx):

```
Dim result = CInt(BitConverter.ToInt16(req, 0))
```